# Adding Intent to class in Applozic's Messaging SDK

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, applozic

Where should I add the foll.intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConversationActivity.class);            
startActivity(intent);
```

As of now, I've followed Applozic's instructions on github. But I am stuck at this.

I've a MainActivity, ApplozicGcmListenerService Class, GcmInstanceIDListenerService Class,GCMRegistrationUtils Class.

Answer (score 2):

When selecting a contact to chat, you can call the ConversationActivity.java to open the chat window.

For example,

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConversationActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra(ConversationUIService.USER_ID, contact_user_id);
 intent.putExtra(ConversationUIService.DISPLAY_NAME, contact_name);

startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 0):

Before starting ConversationActivity intent you need to make sure that you have done the Applozic registration.

Where should I add the following intent?

> You can start ConversationActivity intent on click of button or an menu option click as your app use case and it will show the list of conversations you have done so far.
>   You can check this sample code [link](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/applozic/mobicomkit/sample/MainActivity.java) and we started the ConversationActivity intent on navigation drawer menu item click